# mysql - multiple select with UNION ALL and count() in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, count, union

I have a DB-table formed like this:

```
ID | pairname | timeframe | value1 | value2 | value3
```

I have about 290 pairnames and 4 timeframes and for each timeframe I will have 250 rows.

Table looks like this:

```
1 | appusd | 1h | 12319 | 129312 | 11111 | 11111
2 | appusd | 1h | 12444 | 123912 | 11221 | 111231
3 | appusd | 4h | 12312 | 123123 | 11111 | 12321
4 | gttusd | 1h | 12342 | 123123 | 11111 | 12321
5 | gttusd | 4h | 12342 | 123123 | 11111 | 12321
```

I run a PHP script, that will first fill the DB with values and then check every hour if values are on current.

In PHP I loop first to get all pairnames I need from an other table. Inside of this loop, I loop through the 4 different timeframes to create this SELECT:

```
(
SELECT value1, timeframe
FROM db1
WHERE pairname = 'blabla'
AND timeframe = '1h'
ORDER BY value1 DESC
LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT value1, timeframe
FROM db1
WHERE pairname = 'blabla'
AND timeframe = '4h'
ORDER BY value1 DESC
LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT value1, timeframe
FROM db1
WHERE pairname = 'blabla'
AND timeframe = '8h'
ORDER BY value1 DESC
LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT value1, timeframe
FROM db1
WHERE pairname = 'blabla'
AND timeframe = '2h'
ORDER BY value1 DESC
LIMIT 2
)
```

it works nicely. But because I have 290 queries out of the loop, it takes some time. (about 9 secs with all the other script part, that's ok.)

Now I do not only want the last 2 entries of each pairname/timeframe but also to count how many entries I have, I need to count each row of each pairname/timeframe.

```
(
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS rawnr
FROM db1
WHERE pairname = 'blabla'
AND timeframe = '1h'
)
UNION ALL (
...
)
```

Now I have another 290 queries. and script-time doubles. It's getting slow. Is it possible to count() and select at the same time, if I have this UNION ALL inside of my SELECT?

I've tried it, and it does not work, maybe because of the "limit 2" inside of the same select? I also tried to UNION ALL the count() into a new select, and this did not work either, because UNION wants the same amount of columns.

My solution works with about 17 seconds script-time. After this, I will have to check each result if it's up to date, pull new data from another server and then also delete/add new entries. This will definitely exceed my script-time, and I will have to find a solution for refreshing the script after certain amount of pairname/timeframe editing. (if you know how to reload a php-script at a certain point, that would be also fine!)

EDIT to see the other tables and the script:
The pairname is combined out of 2 names. Name one could be "app" and second "usd".

1st table with names formed like this:

```
nameID | name | active | value1 | value2 | value3
```

2nd table contains which names can be paired.

```
pairID | nameID1 | nameID2 | active | somevalue
```

I check first which "names" are active and then which pairs are "active". After this I combine the names to get: "appusd". This pairname I use in the third table, there I save all the data to this pairnames.
The reason I use "pairname" as a own raw is, that the data I fill in comes from an API that wants exactly this "pairname", so I can handle data better later on.

The thing is, that I do not want all names, and not all pairname-combinations. 
All this has a script-time of 0,7 sec. So it's fine.

```
$tradeagainst = array("ABC","USD");
$timeframearr = array("1h","2h","4h","8h");
$tradeagainstsql = "";
$namepairarr = array();
$insert = "";
$ticker = array();
    $tabelle = "names";
    $tabelle2 = "namepairs";    
    $sqlsc = "SELECT NameID, shortname, nametyp
        FROM ".$tabelle."
        ORDER BY shortname ASC";
    $resultsc = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlsc);
    $nameshortnamearr = array();
    $nameIDarr = array();
    while($rowc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsc)){
        $nameshortnamearr []= $rowc["shortname"];
        $nameIDarr []= $rowc["NameID"];
            if(in_array($rowc["shortname"],$tradeagainst)){
        if($tradeagainstsql == ""){
            $tradeagainstsql .= " AND (".$tabelle2.".tradenameID = '".$rowc["NameID"]."'";
        }else{
            $tradeagainstsql .= " OR ".$tabelle2.".tradenameID = '".$rowc["NameID"]."'";
        }
            }
    }
    if($tradeagainstsql != ""){
        $tradeagainstsql .= ") ";
    }
    $sqls = "SELECT ".$tabelle.".*, GROUP_CONCAT(".$tabelle2.".tradenameID) as trID
        FROM ".$tabelle."
        LEFT JOIN ".$tabelle2." ON ".$tabelle.".NameID = ".$tabelle2.".NameID
        WHERE ".$tabelle.".active != '1'
        AND ".$tabelle2.".active != '1'
        ".$tradeagainstsql."
        GROUP BY ".$tabelle.".NameID
        ORDER BY ".$tabelle.".shortname";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqls);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $nameID = $row["NameID"];
        $shortname = $row["shortname"];
        $active = $row["active"];
        $nametyp = $row["nametyp"];
        $namepairsarr = explode(",",$row["trID"]);
        foreach($namepairsarr as $trnameID){
                    $ct++;
                    $namepair = $shortname.$nameshortnamearr[array_search($trnameID, $nameIDarr)];
                    $namepairarr []= $namepair;
        }
        }
    }
```

this first part I do, to get the $namepairarr. It is also dynamically, to be able to set up, the  $tradeagainst, $timeframearr;

The second part is this one:

```
$tabelle3 = "namepairdata";
$updatearray = array();
foreach($namepairarr as $namepair){
    $sqlnp = "";
    $sqlnpcount = "";
    foreach($timeframearr as $timeframe){
    if($sqlnp == ""){
        $sqlnp .= "(SELECT value1, timeframe
        FROM ".$tabelle3." 
        WHERE pair = '".$namepair."' AND timeframe = '".$timeframe."' ORDER BY value1 DESC LIMIT 2)";
        $sqlnpcount .= "(SELECT count(*) AS rawcount
        FROM ".$tabelle3." 
        WHERE pair = '".$namepair."' AND timeframe = '".$timeframe."')";    
    }else{
        $sqlnp .= " UNION ALL (SELECT value1, timeframe
        FROM ".$tabelle3." 
        WHERE pair = '".$namepair."' AND timeframe = '".$timeframe."' ORDER BY value1 DESC LIMIT 2)";
        $sqlnpcount .= " UNION ALL (SELECT count(*) AS rawcount
        FROM ".$tabelle3." 
        WHERE pair = '".$namepair."' AND timeframe = '".$timeframe."')";    
    }
    }

    $resultnp = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlnp);
    $resultnpc = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlnpcount);
    $rowsvalue1 = array();
    $rowstimeframe = array();
    $rowscount = array();
    while($rowkl = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultnp)){
    $rowsvalue1 []= $rowkl['value1'];
    $rowstimeframe []= $rowkl['timeframe'];
    }
    while($rowklc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultnpc)){
    $rowscount []= $rowklc['rawcount'];
    }
    $rc = 0;
    foreach($timeframearr as $timeframe){
    $value11 = "";
    $value12 = "";
    $timeframecount = $rowscount[$rc]; $rc++;
    for($ints = 0; $ints < count($rowstimeframe); $ints++){
        if($timeframe == $rowstimeframe[$ints]){
            if($value11 == ""){
            $value11 = $rowsvalue1[$ints];
            }else{
            $value12 = $rowsvalue1[$ints];
            }
        }
    }
    $updatearray []= array($namepair,$timeframe,$value11,$value12,$timeframecount);
    }
```

Finally I get an array $updatearray, which I will have to do something with.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: "In PHP I loop first to get all pairnames I need from an other table. Inside of this loop, I loop through the 4 different timeframes to create this SELECT" May we see that code please?

Comment: @Nick 5.7.28 ..

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld the loopling in php works and creates this SQL-Statement, also printed this statement, to be able to print it here. Do you think, I should increase my PHP-part to make more of the work through SQL instead of PHP-loops?

Comment: @wingman - generally when working with databases. Let the database-manager do the work! That's what it is intended for! So I would yes on your question.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I edited the post with the rest of the code.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what's going in your db-structure but is it nos just doing something like https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php to get the counted values for each group? And in the first query,just SELECT value1, timeframe
FROM db1 GROUP BY pariname. I don't understand why you're creating a lot of sql-queries dynamically.